# UIView with cut out segment and shadow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer

My problem is following: I'm trying to cut out a segment out of custom UIView and apply a shadow effect to this view.

In a custom UIView class, I did this:

Created two layers - shadow and mask. Added a shadow layer as a sublayer for this custom view. Then I created a new view, set its mask as the mask layer and added it as a subview to the custom view.

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
CGFloat radius = 40;
float startAngle = -M_PI;
float endAngle = 0;

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];

[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(self.bounds)+radius/1.8)];
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(self.bounds)+radius/1.8) radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];

CAShapeLayer *shadowLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
shadowLayer.frame = self.bounds;
shadowLayer.path = path.CGPath;
shadowLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 2;
shadowLayer.masksToBounds = NO;
shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0);
shadowLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;


CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
maskLayer.masksToBounds = NO;
maskLayer.path = path.CGPath;
maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
maskLayer.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

[self.layer addSublayer:shadowLayer];

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
[self addSubview:view];
```

That is what I want to achieve -

[image]

and this is what I actually get

[image]

If I set clipToBounds = YES, it will cut off the desired shadow effect.

There would be absolutely no problem, if I wanted to cut of a semicircle. Because in this case the semicircle path fully sits inside of view bounds.

[image]

But I do need to achieve a result shown in the first image.
I was thinking about building the path line by line, but the problem occurs when it comes to this arc, and the result will probably not be so accurate.

Does anyone have ideas how it could be done?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
If the issue is that the path is wrong, do no composite the path in code using a circle and guessing the coordinates.  Instead you should export the coordinates actual artwork and use the artwork coordinates for the curve.  It looks like you have a sketch file so the easiest way to do this is to copy and paste into [paint code](https://www.paintcodeapp.com) which will give you the code for the curve, but in the event you don't have paint code (you should, its amazing for this kind of stuff) you can export the curve as SVG from sketch.  If you open the resulting SVG in a text editor you will see its in human readable XML and you can extract the control points from your Bezier curve from there.

Comment: That's what I actually did. I created two layers -  shadow and mask layer. I added shadow layer as a sublayer for the custom view. And after I created a new view and set it mask as a mask layer. And it produces this strange effect.

Comment: Thank you! PaintCode is such an amazing tool! It did its job and now everything works almost perfectly! The only thing is that all curve points are needed to be adjusted to produce the same effect on different device sizes. I should be able to manage that :)