# Non-regular shaped UIView with hit testing (workable with Gestures) on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer

I want to be able to create a view that I can assign a gesture to, that is irregular in shape and have the gesture only trigger when touched inside the irregular shape of the view.

My use case is that we put some slide-in options in a tableView cell when touching a button in the cell and we want to prohibit touching anything except those slide-in options when they are active, and touching anywhere else should just close them and restore normal access.  So this irregular view is basically the whole screen with a box cut out of it where the active tableview cell is with the slide-in options and only touching that cell should be active and the rest trapped by the gesture which triggers a close of the options and dismissal of this special irregular touch-catching view.

It appears I need to make the view's `hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?` function return correctly and it should work.  The problem is that my version of this function does not seem to work correctly and I am not sure why.  Based on the even/odd test described in the docs, my debugging shows it should work.

The actual fill with background color of the view shows the correct stuff so it is just the hit test that seems to be off.  I touch and my gesture ends up calling the hitTest which returns true when it seems that it should return false and in the debugger looking at the path shows that a line to the outside drawn from the point would pass two path lines.

My class drew inspiration from [UIView with cut out segment and shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47490658/uiview-with-cut-out-segment-and-shadow) and https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQIrregularView

My class:

```
class CutView: UIView {
    var rectsArray: [CGRect]?

    convenience init(frame: CGRect, rectsArray: [CGRect]) {
        self.init(frame: frame)

        self.rectsArray = rectsArray
 
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: frame)
        
        for holeRect in rectsArray {
            path.append(UIBezierPath(rect: holeRect))
        }
        
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer.masksToBounds = false
        path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
        maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
        
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
    
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if let shapeLayer = self.layer.mask as? CAShapeLayer, let contains = shapeLayer.path?.contains(point), contains {
            return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically, in the debugger, the `.contains(point)` is returning true.

Thanks for any insight on this (or alternative ways of achieving what I want to achieve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the path from a `CAShapeLayer` gets a `CGPath`, so you need to use:

```
contains(_:using:transform:)
```

[docs page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpath/2427117-contains)

Here's a modified version of your class, along with an example controller:

```
class CutView: UIView {
    var rectsArray: [CGRect]?
    
    convenience init(frame: CGRect, rectsArray: [CGRect]) {
        self.init(frame: frame)
        
        self.rectsArray = rectsArray
        
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: frame)
        
        for holeRect in rectsArray {
            path.append(UIBezierPath(rect: holeRect))
        }
        
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer.masksToBounds = false
        path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
        maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
        
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
    
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

        if !self.frame.contains(point) {
            print("point is outside view frame")
            return nil
        }
        if let shapeLayer = self.layer.mask as? CAShapeLayer {
            if let path = shapeLayer.path {
                let pointInHole = !path.contains(point, using: .evenOdd, transform: .identity)
                print("Point is in a \"hole\"?", pointInHole)
                if pointInHole {
                    return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let r: [CGRect] = [
            CGRect(x: 80, y: 120, width: 100, height: 50),
            CGRect(x: 120, y: 240, width: 60, height: 120),
        ]
        let v = CutView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 80, width: 240, height: 400), rectsArray: r)
        v.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        view.addSubview(v)
    }

}
```

I might have the `return super.hitTest(point, with: event)` and `return nil` flipped - not sure which way you want it returned.

But, this example controller will print to the debug console, letting you know if the point is outside the view itself, or true/false for "in a hole."

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.  The contains(point:) came up as an auto complete.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Strange that Xcode doesn't even flag a warning for me.  Appreciate it@

Comment: @chadbag -- `contains(point:)` doesn't throw a warning, because it is completely valid. However, with a `cgPath`, the path's bounding box is considered the "path." If we call `.contains(point:)` on a `UIBezierPath` *which has `.usesEvenOddFillRule = true`*, we get the "expected" result (holes are not part of the path).

Comment: Thanks.  I finally got this tested today (got a new work computer that took a while to get back to being able to do real work).  The CG stuff is not my forté and I appreciate you explaining the contains() differences.  I flipped the `if pointInHole` condition to meet my needs but this works for my needs.